# Why doesn't [0-9]+ match "123" in "123 abc" with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I tried-

```
echo "abc 456" | sed 's/[0-9]+/& &/'
```

and was expecting "abc 456 456", but it simply prints "abc 456".

Isn't [0-9]+ supposed to find '1 or more' digits?

Also, if i try-

```
echo "abc 456" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'
```

it prints " abc 456". Notice the space before abc. Does that mean the 1st character is a digit?

Comment: `'s/[0-9]*/& &/'` is easy: `*` matches 0-or-more, so it simply matched 0 digits. This requires no assertion that any character ("first" or otherwise) is a digit at all.

Comment: in first example you have to add sed -r OR \ before +

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using the `-r` flag to `sed`, it uses BRE syntax rather than ERE. `+` is an ERE extension.

```
echo "abc 456" | sed -r 's/[0-9]+/& &/'
```

---

As for the other question branch: `*` matches 0-or-more characters, so

```
echo "abc 456" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'
```

...doesn't require any digits to exist at all (and is in fact able to match an empty string), so it doesn't reveal anything about whether the starting position is considered numeric.

Comment: @hek2mgl, my second example was quoting their own code, not providing any modifier showing how to change it. I don't see a point in correcting it something inherently broken, whereas the first snippet makes enough sense to have clear intent to it.

Answer (score -1):

sed knows two types of regex, basic and extended, in short: use `echo "abc 456" | sed -r 's/[0-9]+/& &/'` to enable extended regex, which support `+` without quoting. Or use `\+` instead of the `+` in your original command (sed in basic regex mode).

Comment: `\+` is a GNU extension; POSIX doesn't require BRE to support it.